# How can we show that a nondegenerate "open" triangle is a $2$-dimensioal $C^\infty$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

How can we show that a nondegenerate triangle $\Delta$ (without the edges) is a $2$-dimensioal $C^\infty$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$?

Intuitively, the claim is obvious to me: For any point $p$ of $\Delta$, we could take an open ball $B$ around $p$ and rotate and translate $B$ such that the open circle given by the intersection of $B$ with $\Delta$ lies in the $(x,y)$-plane.

But how do we need to write this down rigorously?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec r_i$, $1\le i\le 3$,  be the vertices. Then consider $$\vec r \mapsto \bigl(\vec r\cdot(\vec r_2-\vec r_1),\vec r\cdot (\vec r_3-\vec r_1), (\vec r-\vec r_1)\cdot ((\vec r_3-\vec r_1)\times(\vec r_2-\vec r_1))\bigr ) .$$ It maps the plane containing $\Delta$ to the $xy$-plane.

Comment: If $p_0$ is a point of a plane with normal $n=(a,b,c)$, then the plane equation is $n\cdot(p-p_0)=ax+by+cz+d=0$, where $d=-n\cdot p_0$. In order to map this to the $xy$-plane, we need to translate by $(0,0,-d/c)$ and rotate by an angle $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ with $\cos\theta=c/|n|$ around the axis $(b,-a,0)/|n|$. Now, if the triangle is $(p_0,p_1,p_2)$, then $n=(p-p_0)\times(p_2-p_0)$. This leads to a different map than yours. How do you derived your map?

Comment: Something is definitively wrong with your map. For example, the $z$-component of $r_2$ under your map is equal to $|r_2-r_1|^2\ne0$ and hence the mapped $r_2$ doesn't lie in the $xy$-plane.

Answer (score 1):

The $\Sigma_0:=\ (x,y)$ plane is clearly a submanifold. By rotation and translation - which are smooth diffeomorphisms - the space is mapped to itself, $\Sigma_0$ is mapped to an arbitrary affine plane. 
So, the plane $\Sigma$, which contains the triangle, is a submanifold, and $\Delta$ is an open subset of $\Sigma$, so it's a submanifold of $\Sigma$, hence also of $\Bbb R^3$.